# Remove part of an item in list

Tags: python

I have a list like

```
['pkg1==0.1; python_version < "a.b"', 'pkg2==0.6', 'pkg3>=0.4']
```

which is from the `requirements.txt` file.

I want to remove the `; python_version < "3.7"` part so that the items are always the package names, version operator and versions like `'pkg1==0.1'`

Any idea on how to do it with regex (`re`) will be appreciated.

I thought about using `re.compile()` but I'm not exactly sure how to match the python_version part and trim only that part.

Comment: isn't replace enough? `replace(">=", "==").replace(">", "==")` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rely on `;` char as a beginning of redundant part:

```
lst = ['pkg1==0.1; python_version < "a.b"', 'pkg2==0.6', 'pkg3>=0.4']
pat = re.compile(r'; python_version .+$')
lst = [pat.sub('', p) for p in lst]
print(lst)
```

---

```
['pkg1==0.1', 'pkg2==0.6', 'pkg3>=0.4']
```

Comment: I question whether the `$` in your pattern actually accomplishes anything even if it shouldn't hurt.

Comment: But this only works when the ';' is followed by ' python_version'. It's not clear whether the OP meant it to be that restrictive (I don't think so).

Answer (score 0):

here in the pattern

\s* :  matches zero or more whitespace characters

".*?" :  matches any sequence of characters within double quotes.

and rest of the pattern gives literal match as per the OP's format

```
import re

li = ['pkg1==0.1; python_version<"3.7"', 'pkg2==0.6', 'pkg3>=0.4']
pattern = r';\s*python_version\s*([<>=!]=?)?\s*".*?"'
op= [re.sub(pattern, '', item) for item in li]
print(op)
```

Output:

```
['pkg1==0.1', 'pkg2==0.6', 'pkg3>=0.4']
```

Comment: Is the operator always going to be `<`? The OP says, "... so that the items are always the package names, version operator and versions like 'pkg1==0.1'". I interpret this to mean that *any* python_version part should be removed.

Comment: @Booboo just realised, updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You specifically asked for a solution using `re`, but unless that's a hard requirement (why?), you could also just use `str.split`. This should be much simpler:

```
>>> req = ['pkg1==0.1; python_version < "a.b"', 'pkg2==0.6', 'pkg3>=0.4']
>>> [r.split(";")[0] for r in req]
['pkg1==0.1', 'pkg2==0.6', 'pkg3>=0.4']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code just removes a ';' and anything that follows (whether it is 'python_version' or something else) in an input requirement.

```py
import re

requirements = ['pkg1==0.1; python_version < "a.b"', 'pkg2==0.6', 'pkg3>=0.4']

pattern = re.compile(r'(.*?);.*')
requirements = [pattern.sub(r'\1', requirement) for requirement in requirements]
print(requirements)
```

Prints:

```None
['pkg1==0.1', 'pkg2==0.6', 'pkg3>=0.4']
```

**Explanation**

The regex pattern is `(.*?);.*`.

1. `(.*?)` - Since this is followed by a ';', this will match all characters up to but not including the first ';' character. The match will be Group 1.
2. `;.*` - This will match the first ';' and any characters that follow it up to and including the end of the requirement.

If the pattern matches an input requirement, the entire requirement will be replaced by whatever is in capture group 1, i.e. just the characters up to but not including the first ';'.